# I have 1000+ photos with intact metadata. I want to list the dates taken

Tags: metadata

I have 1000+ photos with intact metadata.  I want to list the dates taken in tabular form with the photo image included.  How can I do this?

Comment: I would like a photo service type org to do it so I have a record/receipt etc.

Comment: Questions seeking specific product or service recommendations, where the answer is likely to be either entirely personal or short-lived as a result of changing markets, are off topic here. Please rephrase your question to describe the problem you're trying to solve or what you do not understand that prevents you from determining the answer yourself.

Comment: List where? On the screen? Or you wan tto create a PDF or Excel with the data. For screen, a file explorer can do a preview and list the file name + file timestamp, and some others (including IIRC the Windows file explorer) can also list some fields from the EXIF data, including the recorded shooting time.

Answer (score -1):

EXIFTool Is free and should be able to do this for you.

Comment: Any examples or idea how? Exiftool is command-line only, so displaying photo image included (as the OP asks) with just Exiftool seems questionable to me.